# Extra commas at beginning and end of csv rows, how to remove?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

So I have a .csv file where each row looks like this:

`,11:00:14,4,5.,93.7,0.01,0.0,7,20,0.001,10,49.3,0.01,
,11:00:15,4,5.,94.7,0.04,0.5,7,20,0.005,10,49.5,0.04,`

when it should look like this:

`11:00:14,4,5.,93.7,0.01,0.0,7,20,0.001,10,49.3,0.01
11:00:15,4,5.,94.7,0.04,0.5,7,20,0.005,10,49.5,0.04`

I think that this is the reason why pandas is not creating data frames properly. What can I do to remove these commas?

The code generating the original csv file is

```
def tsv2csv():

# read tab-delimited file
with open(file_location + tsv_file,'r') as fin:
    cr = csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
    filecontents = [line for line in cr]

# write comma-delimited file (comma is the default delimiter)
# give the exact location of the file
#"newline=''" at the end of the line stops there being spaces between each row
with open(new_csv_file,'w', newline='') as fou:
    cw = csv.writer(fou, quotechar='', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    cw.writerows(filecontents)
```

Comment: What is the code that generates the original CSV file?

Comment: I've added the code in the main post

Answer (score 4):

You can use `usecols` to specify the columns you want to import as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

csv_df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv', header=None, usecols=range(1,13))
```

This will skip the first and last empty columns.

Comment: This comes up with 'ValueError: Usecols do not match names.' I'm afraid I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to pandas so I'm not sure if this is an easy fix

Comment: it works for me, with the csv sample you provided, maybe the real file is different?

Comment: yeh that was only a subsection of it as the first 15 lines or so is user info

Comment: If you have a header, try removing the header option, the important bit is usecols.

Answer (score 3):

The trailing commas correspond to missing data. When loading in your dataframe, they're loaded in as NaNs, so all you'd need to do is get rid of it, either using `dropna` or by slicing them out -

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None).dropna(how='all', axis=1)
```

Or,

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None).iloc[:, 1:-1]
```

```
df

         1   2    3     4     5    6   7   8      9   10    11    12
0  11:00:14   4  5.0  93.7  0.01  0.0   7  20  0.001  10  49.3  0.01
1  11:00:15   4  5.0  94.7  0.04  0.5   7  20  0.005  10  49.5  0.04
```

Comment: Glad I do an iloc solution. That’s the most generic I’d say.

Answer (score -1):

You can strip any character at the beginning and end of a text by using `strip` and give a string with the characters you wan't to escape as an argument.

```
x = ',11:00:14,4,5.,93.7,0.01,0.0,7,20,0.001,10,49.3,0.01,'
print x.strip(',')
>11:00:14,4,5.,93.7,0.01,0.0,7,20,0.001,10,49.3,0.01
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure If It Works in you case, bit have you tried import:

```
    df = pd.read_csv('filename', sep=';')
```